# TabView does not respect selection binding when displayed modally

Tags: swiftui, tabview, xcode12

Considering the below code, I would expect my TabView to show the randomly calculated image when my tab view is displayed, however this is not the case. It will always display the first image at index 0. If I hardcode the selection in the TabView initialiser (i.e. `.constant(n)`) then it will display the chosen image correctly. I have filed a radar (FB7844985) on this, but want to check that I am not missing something obvious?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let assets: [String] = (1...32).map { "preview_\($0)"}
    
    @State private var selection: Int = 0
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Random element") {
                selection = Int.random(in: 1...32)
                isPresented = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            SlideshowView(selection: $selection, assets: assets)
        }
    }
}

struct SlideshowView: View {
    @Binding var selection: Int
    var assets: [String]
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(assets.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                Image(assets[index])
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is not in modality (ie showing in sheet), but in that `TabView` does not read initial (!) selection (and this is definitely a SwiftUI bug)

Here is workaround (tested with Xcode12 / iOS 14 on replicated code)

[image: demo]

```
struct SlideshowView: View {
    @Binding var selection: Int
    var assets: [String]
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(assets.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                Image(assets[index])
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
        .onAppear {
            // WORKAROUND: simulate change of selection on appear !!
            let value = selection
            selection = -1
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                selection = value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So confusing when this happened and it's hard to find any info about this SwiftUI bug, even 3 years later.